# Retrieve data between two dates in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I am using an eloquent query to retrieve data from a table. The table columns look like this:

```
id   started_at   finished_at   
1    2016-06-01   2016-06-30  
2    2016-05-03   2016-05-28
```

What I want to do is, given a `$date` (ex: 2016-06-18 ) and get the data of the row, that the `$date` between started at and finished_at columns.

I have found `whereBetween` clauses in [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses), but I do not have an idea to use it correctly.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you can use Carbon then this code will work fine for you.

```
$dateS = new Carbon('first day of January 2016');
$dateE = new Carbon('first day of November 2016');
$result = ModelName::whereBetween('created_at', [$dateS->format('Y-m-d')." 00:00:00", $dateE->format('Y-m-d')." 23:59:59"])->get();
```

Or you can check the issue by debugging query using `DB::enableQueryLog();` and `DB::getQueryLog();` functions like

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
$dateS = new Carbon('first day of January 2016');
$dateE = new Carbon('first day of November 2016');
$result = ModelName::whereBetween('created_at', [$dateS->format('Y-m-d')." 00:00:00", $dateE->format('Y-m-d')." 23:59:59"])->get();
var_dump($result, DB::getQueryLog());
```

Answer (score 13):

Try to do something like this:

```
$date1 = Carbon::today()->toDateString();
$date2 = Carbon::today()->toDateString();

$myModel = MyModel::find(1);
$myModel->whereBetween('created_at', [$date1, $date2]);
$myModel->get();
```

Of course, you will need to change the dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whereBetween something like this:-

```
ModelName::whereBetween('date',['2022-08-01','2022-10-30'])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Import carbon class in your controller

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

For date time column:

```
ModelName::whereBetween('column_name',[Carbon::parse('2016-06-01')->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'),Carbon::parse('2016-06-30')->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59')])->get();
```

For date column

```
ModelName::whereBetween('column_name',[Carbon::parse('2016-06-01')->format('Y-m-d'),Carbon::parse('2016-06-30')->format('Y-m-d')])->get();
```

***Note: date may come from user input so carbon will format the date.***