# Raw query to Laravel Query

Tags: mysql, laravel

Raw query to Laravel Query

```
SELECT * FROM plans_subscriptions WHERE starts_on BETWEEN "2019-07-30" AND "2019-07-26" or expires_on BETWEEN "2019-07-20" AND "2019-07-22"
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Comment: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40425095/10182897) might help

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You are expected to put some effort in solving your problem yourself. If you have tried something but are stuck then share what you have tried and we can work with you from there. Dumping a query and asking "raw query to laravel query" is not even a real question. It's more like a demand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want object response then use this :

```
PlansSubscriptions::whereBetween('starts_on', ["2019-07-30", "2019-07-26"]);
                 ->orWhereBetween('expires_on', ["2019-07-20", "2019-07-22"]);
                 ->get();
```

If you want array response then use this :

```
PlansSubscriptions::whereBetween('starts_on', ["2019-07-30", "2019-07-26"]);
                 ->orWhereBetween('expires_on', ["2019-07-20", "2019-07-22"]);
                 ->get()->toArray();
```

We can format the date like this :

```
$start = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($request->input('from_date')));
$end = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($request->input('to_date')));
```

and use that variable in query like this:

```
PlansSubscriptions::whereBetween('starts_on', [$start, $end]);
                 ->orWhereBetween('expires_on', ["2019-07-20", "2019-07-22"]);
                 ->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: can we use above query with and rather than or

Comment: here we are using or with second whereBetween condition can we use and with this

Comment: Like this SELECT * FROM `plans_subscriptions` WHERE `starts_on` BETWEEN "2019-06-02" AND "2019-07-26" and `expires_on` BETWEEN "2019-07-20" AND "2019-07-22"

Comment: Yes, just remove the or from orWhereBetween and small w Like this:
"PlansSubscriptions::whereBetween('starts_on', ["2019-07-30", "2019-07-26"])->whereBetween('expires_on', ["2019-07-20", "2019-07-22"]);
                 ->get()->toArray();"

Answer (score 0):

```php
 PlansSubscriptions::whereBetween('starts_on', ["2019-07-30", "2019-07-26"]);
                 ->orWhereBetween('expires_on', ["2019-07-20", "2019-07-22"]);
                 ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
$users = DB::table('plans_subscriptions')
->where(function ($query){
  $query->whereBetween('starts_on', ['2019-07-30', '2019-07-26'])
        ->orWhereBetween('starts_on', ['2019-07-20', '2019-07-22']);
})
->get();
```